# T4 MVC 3 templates generates 88 errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, t4mvc

I have downloaded the following zip. http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/Download/f0f3664d-3199-4095-bb15-815cf9f3ef2e

I did update the MVCSitemap packige in the website project by NUGET.
After that I get a lot of errors (88) generated by my t4 template. Can't find a way to fix this.

http://twitpic.com/4176yb

When not updating this packige everything works as expected and I can build the project. Somehow I can't edit a thing in my project without getting this big load of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: Remove all t4 files from the project. Add them again by NUGET and everything works again.

Microsoft guys this should be fixed. t4mvc shouldn't generate this errors when updating nuget package.

Comment: Please open a bug on http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/ or http://nuget.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild the whole solution and then run the T4 custom tool